# Can I use malloc with references instead of pointers?

Tags: c

```
static Player players[32];

Player* Player_constructor() {
    Player* player = malloc(sizeof(Player));
    // Do some initializations
    return player;
}
...
...
...
players[0] = Player_constructor();
```

The issue is that `players[0]` is type `Player` and `Player_constructor` is type `Player*`.

How can I overcome this issue? Will using references help?

Comment: C doesn't have references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need dynamic allocation here: your array of `Player` structures can be used directly, without `malloc`. One simple way to deal with initialization is rewriting your `Player_constructor` as follows:

```
void Player_constructor(Player* player) {
    // Do some initializations
}
...
Player_constructor(&players[0]);
```

Comment: Using this solution means I don't have to worry about freeing stuff later to prevent memory leaks, right?

Comment: This solution is fantastic then!

Answer (score 1):

it should be

```
static Player *players[32];
```

Comment: So what should I free? All I have to do is `free(players)` and I won't have memory leaks, right?

Comment: @user2924308 No, `players` is statically allocated. You must instead free the *elements* of that array (`players[i]` for `i` from 0 to 31).

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array of pointers instead of structs:

```
static Player * players[32];
```